# update table by concatenating a string and current value

Tags: mysql

Need to update table `banners` so that column `src` instead of `something.jpg` would be `banners/something.jpg`;

```
update banners set src = 'banners/' . currentValue
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
update banners set src = CONCAT('banners/', src)
```

Comment: @puerto - This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) should be accepted.